# Passing WINDOWS text to BATCH FIle

Tags: batch-file, clipboard

BATCH FILE:
How do I pass selected text (grabbed from any place-WEB PAGE, OFFICE app, DOS WINDOW, ETC) and use it as a value or a string inside of a BAT File.  I want to by-pass the CMD window.  Basically, I was to select my text as step one and kick-off the BAT as step 2.
I have not tried anything to this point as I cannot find anything to match what I am trying to do.  Thanks for any guidance you guys can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Windows only has a command to copy text from command prompt. If you want to paste you have to make your own.

From https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/printclipexe-prints-any-text-or.html

Two files follow

PrintClip.exe prints any text or filenames on the clipboard to a StdOutn. Most programs cannot print filenames on the clipboard.

```
 REM PrintClip.bat
 REM This file compiles PrintClip.vb to PrintClip.exe
 REM PrintClip.exe prints any text or filenames on the clipboard to a StdOut. Most programs cannot print filenames on the clipboard.
 REM To use 
 REM PrintClip
 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:exe /out:"%~dp0\PrintClip.exe" "%~dp0\PrintClip.vb" /verbose
 pause
```

---

```
'PrintClip.vb
 Imports System
 Imports System.IO
 Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
 Imports Microsoft.Win32

 Public Module PrintClip
        Public Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Integer
        Public Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As IntPtr
        Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
        Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Integer
        Public Declare UNICODE Function DragQueryFileW Lib "shell32.dll" (ByVal HDROP As Integer, ByVal UINT As Integer, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Integer) As Integer

        Public Const CF_TEXT = 1
        Public Const CF_BITMAP = 2
        Public Const CF_METAFILEPICT = 3
        Public Const CF_SYLK = 4
        Public Const CF_DIF = 5
        Public Const CF_TIFF = 6
        Public Const CF_OEMTEXT = 7
        Public Const CF_DIB = 8
        Public Const CF_PALETTE = 9
        Public Const CF_PENDATA = 10
        Public Const CF_RIFF = 11
        Public Const CF_WAVE = 12
        Public Const CF_UNICODETEXT = 13
        Public Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
        Public Const CF_HDROP = 15
        Public Const CF_OWNERDISPLAY = &H80
        Public Const CF_DSPTEXT = &H81
        Public Const CF_DSPBITMAP = &H82
        Public Const CF_DSPMETAFILEPICT = &H83
        Public Const CF_DSPENHMETAFILE = &H8E


        Sub Main()
 '                On Error Resume Next
                Dim Ret as IntPtr
                If OpenClipboard(0) <> 0 then
                        If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT) <> 0 then
                                Ret = GetClipboardData( CF_UNICODETEXT)
                                Console.writeline(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Ret))
                                Environment.ExitCode = 0
                        ElseIf IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_hDrop) <> 0 then
                                Dim TotalCount as Integer
                                Dim FName as String
                                Dim hDrop as IntPtr
                                hDrop = GetClipboardData( CF_hDrop)
                                FName = Space(33000)
                                TotalCount = DragQueryFileW(hDrop,  &hFFFFFFFF, FName, 33000)
                                For x = 0 to TotalCount - 1
                                        FName = Space(33000)
                                        If DragQueryFileW(hDrop,  x, FName, 33000) <> 0 then
                                                Console.writeline(Trim(FName))
                                        End If
                                Next
                                Environment.ExitCode = 0
                        Else
                                Environment.ExitCode = 1
                                Console.writeline("No text or filenames on clipboard")
                        End If
                        CloseClipboard()
                Else
                        Environment.ExitCode = err.lastdllerror
                        Console.Writeline("Clipboard is locked by another application")
                End If

        End Sub
 End Module
```

Comment: I will look at this option as well, also, thank you too for the prompt response!